# Play optional query parameter not parsing

Tags: scala, playframework, routes, playframework-2.1, query-string

I am trying a [documented](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaRouting) routes example for Play 2.1.1

**routes**

```
# The version parameter is optional. E.g. /api/list-all?version=3.0
GET   /api/list-all         controllers.Api.list(Option[version])
```

And then

```
$ play-2.1.1 compile
[error] /home/paul/server/conf/routes:2: Compilation error[`)' expected but `[' found]
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
GET   /api/list-all         controllers.Api.list(version: Option[String])
```

Comment: Thanks. I already know that way works. I trying to get [this](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaRouting) example to work. Is your answer that the documentation is wrong?

Comment: Documentation is wrong. Looks like it was corrected on the master branch on GitHub last February.

Comment: Huh...it did look really, really weird.

Comment: @PaulDraper: I'd recommend to read documentation for the latest version of Play: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaRouting

Comment: @RadoBuransky, true, I am using 2.1.1, so I thought I'd stick to that documentation :)

Comment: @PaulDraper: Makes sense. I said that just because I have found myself reading old doc only because Google returned it as the first result.